# Change Jquery scroll to page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new to Jquery and I am trying to change the following script without success. The problem is that the donut (for stats) right now load when you scroll the page, if you dont scroll nothing happens. I would like it to load fast when the page load so I tried changing the scroll to onload but it does not work... Any ideas why?

Here is the original code

```
/* Tokan Graph */
    if ($("#tokensale-part").length > 0) {
    function tokan_graph () {
        var scrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop();
        var scrollDistance1 = $('#tokensale-part').offset().top - 100;

        if ( scrollDistance >= (scrollDistance1 - 100) && scrollDistance <= (scrollDistance1 + 100)) {
            $('.donut').listtopie({
              startAngle:270,
              strokeWidth:5,
                hoverEvent:true,
                hoverBorderColor:'#16d5ff',
                hoverAnimate:false,
                drawType:'round',
                speedDraw:150,
                hoverColor:'#ffffff',
                textColor:'#3d1f94',
                strokeColor:'#f2f8fe',
                textSize:'18',
                hoverAnimate:true,
                marginCenter:85,
            });
        }
    }

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        tokan_graph();
    })

    $(window).on("resize", function(){
        $( window ).resize( function(){

          if( w != $( window ).width() ){
            if ( $(window).width() < 767 ){
                $('.donut').listtopie('refresh');
            }
            w = $( window ).width();
          }

        });
    })

  $(".token-graph").addClass("token-graph-right");
  }
  /* Tokan Graph End */
```

So I already changed `$(window).scroll(function(){` to `$(window).onload(function(){` but it keep loading only if you scroll

Comment: Try `$(window).on("load", function(){`.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette why not using `$(document).ready(function(){   });` as long as the document ready is fires when dom is ready when window load fires when all objects are loaded ?

Comment: Good point @BurhamB.Soliman. My comment was just a quick comment... You can try an answer with this since where to put it and how to call `tokan_graph` needs explanations which won't fit in the "comment" limitations. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette as per what shown in the script, the graph will start regarding position of the element, so he needs to override this statement first before getting ride of the scroll event

Comment: hey dude your graph function has a statement to be loaded regarding the offset of the element top, so you need to change this line         `if ( scrollDistance >= (scrollDistance1 - 100) && scrollDistance <= (scrollDistance1 + 100)) {` before changing the scroll event

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman In fact... The only needed part is `$('.donut').listtopie({` inside a document ready... And the `$( window ).resize( function(){` line sould be removed since it is inside a `$(window).on("resize", function(){`... There are a couple things to explain... ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette tottaly agree (Y)

Answer (score 0):

As per what you shown, you need to get rid of the whole scroll event. So you need to remove all related events which binds the graph action on scroll.

Here is how you can solve it simply:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  /* Tokan Graph */
  if ($("#tokensale-part").length > 0) {
    $('.donut').listtopie({
      startAngle: 270,
      strokeWidth: 5,
      hoverEvent: true,
      hoverBorderColor: '#16d5ff',
      hoverAnimate: false,
      drawType: 'round',
      speedDraw: 150,
      hoverColor: '#ffffff',
      textColor: '#3d1f94',
      strokeColor: '#f2f8fe',
      textSize: '18',
      hoverAnimate: true,
      marginCenter: 85,
    });

    $(".token-graph").addClass("token-graph-right");
  }
  /* Tokan Graph End */
})

// Redraw the graph on every window size change.
$(window).on("resize", function(){
  if ($("#tokensale-part").length > 0) {
    $('.donut').listtopie('refresh');
  }
})
```

Comment: mmm... I think the `resize` event handler is needed but needs a cleanout. And you did not add the `document.ready()` ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette for the document.ready, the graph will be loaded once the the length of the selector is greater than 0 , so i think no need for document ready in this case, and about the resize i think  it might be added back

Comment: Well we don't know what `#tokensale-part` is... But as I read it is if the element exist on page load, the graph is drawn... And that is it. It isn't an event listener.

Comment: Can I edit you answer for fun? It will be a "collaborative" answer lol.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yea sure :D you can do it (Y) ...

Comment: Done. So that is how I see it... Not knowing what is `#tokensale-part` and not knowing how the graph really renders. ;)

Comment: we just did the best as per what he gave :D as long as he didn't even included his html, so we can't figure out how it's going on... but still thinking if the `#tokensale-part ` default length is 0 so it will be loaded into the document start as it's default.. so no effect, he might be around to make it clear so we can bind an event depending on what is `#tokensale-part` ??